# Check and Add To Cart depending on Items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to check the cart for ITEM A,

if ITEM A is present add ITEM B,

if BOTH are present DO NOTHING.

I have this code below to work with. Its working but need to check if both items are in cart and not add another item. Thanks for any help.

```
// add item to cart on visit
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $product1_id = 66;
    $product2_id = 88;
    $found = false;
    //check if product1 is in cart
    if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $product1_id )
                $found = true;
        }
        // if product1 found, add product2
        if ( $found )
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product2_id );
    } else {
        // check for product2 here?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Write some commas in the 1st sentence -- it's hard to understand. (I will delete this comment in several minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original code works, here is how I would do it. I have renamed a variable or two for ease of reading.

```
$product_1_in_cart = false;
$product_2_in_cart = false;

if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->id == $product1_id )
            $product_1_in_cart = true;
        if ( $_product->id == $product2_id )
            $product_2_in_cart = true;
    }
    // if product 1 is in cart, and product 2 is not in cart
    if ( $product_1_in_cart && !$product_2_in_cart ){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product2_id );
    }
} else {

}
```